# unstable build with unstable with

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to get the an "UNSTABLE" build instead of

```
    //currentBuild.result='UNSTABLE'

    stage 'Publish Reports'

        allowMissing: false
    ])
}
```

can any one give me a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If `mvn test` fails, it will return a non-zero exit code.  In this case, the `sh` step throws an `AbortException` with "script returned exit code X", causing the Pipeline to stop executing, and being marked as FAILURE.

So, you need to find the Maven configuration that returns exit code `0`, even if there are test failures.  Then the pipeline will continue, and you can parse the test results.

Or, you can check the exit code yourself, e.g. assuming that Maven returns an exit code `123` to denote test failures:

```groovy
// Attempt to execute the tests
int exitCode = sh script: 'mvn test', returnStatus: true

// Check whether testing succeeded, or a known failure code was returned
if (exitCode == 0 || exitCode == 123) {
    // Attempt to parse the test results, if they exist
    junit '**/test-results-dir/TEST-*.xml'

    // At this point, the pipeline will have been marked as 'UNSTABLE',
    // assuming that parsing the results found at least one test failure
} else {
    // Something unexpected happened (e.g. compile failure); stop pipeline.
    // This will cause the pipeline to be marked as 'FAILURE'
    error("Testing failed with exit code ${exitCode}.")
}
```

Comment: Your solution cannot work because as you mention the execution of `mvn test` will throw an `AbortException` if it fails, so your `exitCode` test is unreachable.

Comment: @Pom12 Not if you use the `returnStatus` flag. From the documentation: "Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero status code will cause the step to fail with an exception. If this [returnStatus] option is checked, the return value of the step will instead be the status code."

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you for the tip that is good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

I achieve the exact same behavior using the `junit` step and the Maven option `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`.

Here is an example from my Jenkinsfile :

```
stage('Build') {
    ...
    // Run Maven build and don't fail on errors
    withMaven(
            maven: 'Maven3',
            mavenSettingsConfig: 'provided-config-file') {

        sh "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true"
    }
    // publish test results
    junit '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
}
```

The `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` option make Maven to return 0 if tests failed, instead of 1.

If the return code of a command ran with `sh` is different from 0, the build status is set to `FAILED` and the build stops.

With this option, Maven returns 0 if tests failed, so the build proceeds to the next step.

The `junit` step archive the tests results, and sets the build status to `UNSTABLE` if some tests failed.

Answer (score 1):

The following works, but there must be a better solution.  I'm pretty disappointed with the pipeline support so far on Jenkins 2.19.2, it feels a bit half baked.

```groovy
def runTests() {
  setTestStatus(sh (returnStatus: true, script: 'mvn clean test'))
}

@NonCPS
def setTestStatus(testStatus) {
  if (testStatus == 0) {
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
  } else {
    def testResult = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class)
    currentBuild.result = (testResult != null && testResult.failCount > 0) ? 'UNSTABLE' : 'FAILURE'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [this flag](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore)?

```
-DtestFailureIgnore=true
```